# Editing tags of highly-voted questions

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, editing-help

I was looking at some popular (i.e. highly voted) questions of Keras tag on Stack Overflow, and realized that, despite being viewed a lot of times, a few of those questions are poorly formatted or have a poor grammar. So I decided to edit them and fixed their formatting/grammar. Usually, when editing questions I also pay attention to the tags used because I have the impression that tags help a lot with searching and finding the relevant question(s). So I remove the irrelevant tags (if any), and try to add as much and relevant as possible tags to the question.

However, after I edited one of those questions, which involved removing two of the tags and adding two much more relevant tags, I realized this might have some side-effects: it might change the ranking of OP/answerer(s) in the removed/added tags, and even the answerer(s) might lose some tag badges (and possibly gain some other tag badges). Further, it might affect the developer story of answerer(s) and change their top percentiles.

So I just wanted to know what's the best approach to take when editing these highly-voted questions? Some options coming to my mind:

- Just edit the question's content and don't touch the tags (unless some of them are **absolutely** and **completely** irrelevant).
- Do as I already did (i.e. if you think a tag is not completely irrelevant, but it could be replaced with a more relevant tag then just do it)! It's OK and don't worry about top-user rankings or tag badges of answerer(s) or OP
- I am over-thinking it too much and should not be that much obsessed about such a small matter (i.e. it does not matter whether I edit the tags or not!).

---

For reference, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42081257/revisions) is one of the edits I did (revision #5). My rationale for tag edits:

- I added [loss-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loss-function) because that's the primary topic of the question.
- I added [classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/classification) because those loss functions are usually used in classification problems, and also the OP has mentioned that he/she is working on a classification problem and has reported classification accuracy values.
- I had to remove two tags: I decided to remove [deep-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-learning) because this question could be concerned with shallow networks as well, and is not at all specific to deep models (besides the fact that there is no direct reference to deep learning in question). Also, I removed [neural-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neural-network) because the [conv-neural-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conv-neural-network) was already there and therefore I thought it has a neural network part and also it refers to the specific architecture the OP is using in his/her question (though, I have to confess that I was a bit skeptical on this last decision).

Comment: (why is loss-function a tag...? isn't it just a part of neural networks in the context that anyone knowing how to answer a neural network would likely just be glommed onto the parent tag(s) where necessary?)

Comment: @Makoto Well, if you ask me I would say it deserves its own tag because for example you sometimes ask a question which is just concerned with how to implement a specific loss function (e.g. in Keras/python/sci-kit learn), or which loss function is suitable to use. Further, loss function is not specific to neural networks. Many (almost all of) different machine learning models have and use loss functions.

Answer (score 7):

Addressing your general question: just edit the tags as you see fit, according to the contents of the Q&A. Tag scores and badges shouldn't get in the way of classifying questions appropriately, which is the primary purpose of tags.

(On "as you see fit", it doesn't hurt to note the usual caveats of consulting with Meta and/or tag regulars before large scale retaggings apply; that, however, doesn't have much to do with the popularity of the affected questions.)

Answer (score 5):

> Usually, when editing questions I also pay attention to the tags used because I have the impression that tags help a lot with searching and finding the relevant question(s). So I remove the irrelevant tags (if any), and try to add as much and relevant as possible tags to the question.

This is exactly how you should do edits. Whenever editing, pay attention to the post as whole, including title and tags, to address as many problems as possible at the same time.

> However, after I edited one of those questions, which involved removing two of the tags and adding two much more relevant tags, I realized this might have some side-effects: it might change the ranking of OP/answerer(s) in the removed/added tags, and even the answerer(s) might lose some tag badges (and possibly gain some other tag badges).

Votes and badges shouldn't be a concern here, only technical quality and relevance.

However, one should avoid removing the main programming language tag of a question, since that might make it harder to find and also mess up code highlighting. If a question contains any code, we should try to preserve the language tag of the programming language used. Even if the question isn't about Python programming as such.

So the 2nd edit to that post (which wasn't done by you) is questionable. They removed the Python tag and added manual code highlighting with `<!-- language-all: lang-python -->`. That's a harmful edit - people searching for [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) + [keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keras) etc will no longer find the post. Also, in case the question was about some low traffic niche tag, removing the Python tag could mean that the question wouldn't get any attention from those whom might be able to answer it.

Unfortunately we can only add 5 tags, so it is easy to run out of them. I know too little of the topic to tell if the tags are relevant or if there is enough people following them. If the right kind of people will be able to find the question, then all is well.